# Can I hide a webform?

Tags: webforms

I would like to pilot a webform for a period of time and have the option to hide it vs. delete if needed. How do you hide a webform from your site?

Comment: Hello, yes you can!  what version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 8.1

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8, you can archive your webform if it's closed.

To close your webform, go in the settings of your webform in the "Form" tab. You can schedule the closing too.

When it will closed, you will have the option to archive it in the "General" tab of its settings.

Comment: Thanks :) I did figure that out. However that option doesn't "hide" the form. the title is still displayed.